# Bot Application Core 2.0 - Unauthorized error

Tags: botframework

I have created a project with Bot Application Core 2.0 template and have updated all nuget packages.
It working on emulator without AppId and AppPassword configured, but it got 'UnauthorizedAccessException' when AppId and AppPassword is configured.
[image: screenshot]

I'm following [troubleshoot instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/bot-framework/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems). Direct POST request to auth server is OK, I got Token etc. So my appid and password is OK and there is no instructions for this situation.

Comment: Where does your "Bot Application Core 2.0 template" come from?

Comment: It's going to be very hard to assist you without any code, or any information about your bot.

Comment: See this example https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.NetCore-ApsNetCore2.0

Comment: @NicolasR this is default template from VS2017 http://puu.sh/zFTiV/254a8bfb6c.png

Comment: @JasonSowers there is no specific information about the bot. This is just template with updated all packages + setted `BotId`, `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` in `app.config`. Other code is default.

Comment: Now startup and program classes basically the same as in the sample. appsettings.json the same too (but id and password is configured). Difference is MessagesController. I have dialogs, but the sample have simple echo logic.

Comment: @SUDALV I have VS2017 but there is no Bot Framework category available

Comment: I have also never seen this template in my life. .NET core does not support dialogs in the v3 SDK.  As a workaround you can try what is in this GitHub issue here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3941

Comment: I will try it later, but seems using .net core for bot framework is too early